# How to properly curry with ES6?

Tags: javascript

Say I have,

```
const toUpperCase = word => word.toUpperCase();
const reverse = word => word.split('').reverse().join('')
const toLowerCase = word => word.toLowerCase();
```

How can I do something like,

```
const transformWord = word => toUpperCase(word) => reverse(word) => toLowerCase(word)
console.log(transformWord('abcdefg')) // expected output: gfedcba
```

Comment: Well, you can do this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/7h62woq4/ But you'd have to create a separate pipe function for each number of transformation functions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an array of the functions and `reduce` over them:

```js
const toUpperCase = word => word.toUpperCase();
const reverse = word => word.split('').reverse().join('')
const toLowerCase = word => word.toLowerCase();

const transformWord = word => [toUpperCase, reverse, toLowerCase].reduce((lastVal, fn) => fn(lastVal), word);
console.log(transformWord('abcdefg')) // expected output: gfedcba
```

There's also the [pipeline operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Pipeline_operator) proposal which makes this look a whole lot neater, but that's ages away from being implemented (it's still stage 1):

```
const transformWord = word => word |> toUpperCase |> reverse |> toLowerCase;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a pipe function which reduces the given function by using a parameter.

```js
const
    pipe = (...functions) => input => functions.reduce((acc, fn) => fn(acc), input),
    toUpperCase = word => word.toUpperCase(),
    reverse = word => word.split('').reverse().join(''),
    toLowerCase = word => word.toLowerCase(),
    transformWord = pipe(toUpperCase, reverse, toLowerCase);


console.log(transformWord('abcdefg')) // expected output: gfedcba
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what this has to do with currying. I think you're just looking for function composition:

```
const transformWord = word => toLowerCase(reverse(toUpperCase(word)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const toUpperCase = word => word.toUpperCase();
const reverse = word => word.split('').reverse().join('')
const toLowerCase = word => word.toLowerCase();

const transformWord = word => toLowerCase(reverse(toUpperCase(word)));
console.log(transformWord('abcdefg')) //Output: gfedcba
```

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive approach to write curry function. Curry function returns a function if you pass the transform function and when you pass the word, it will all the transformations and return the result word. Only thing last has to be word.

`transformWord(processA)(processB)(processN)(word)`

```js
const toUpperCase = word => word.toUpperCase();
const reverse = word => word.split('').reverse().join('')
const toLowerCase = word => word.toLowerCase();

const transformWord = arg => {
  const queue = [arg];

  const curry = item => {
    if (typeof item === "string") {
      let word = item;
      while (queue.length > 0) {
        const transform = queue.shift();
        word = transform(word);
      }
      return word;
    } else {
      queue.push(item);
      return curry;
    }
  };
  return curry;
};

console.log(transformWord(toUpperCase)(reverse)(toLowerCase)("abcdefg"));
console.log(transformWord(toUpperCase)("abcdefg"));
```